# What is the validation expression to allow english and arabic and spaces in a textbox

Tags: validation, arabic, validationexception

I need to validate English / Arabic letters only with spaces in a textbox.
I used below validation expressions, it accepts English / Arabic text, But it did not accept any spaces. Can anyone give me the right expression.

```
^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called a `Regular Expression`. To allow whitespaces, you need to add a whitespace to the set.

`^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_ ]+$`

This Regular Expression accepts English, Arabic letters and whitespaces. **It also accetps only whitespace with no letters.**

Comment: yes dear I'm taking about the validation expression of a regular expression. I used this (   ^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_\ ]*$  ) and it works fine for me. @3li